# Lambda interfaces in Kotlin

Tags: android, lambda, interface, kotlin, anonymous-function

I have implemented this `interface` in my `Adapter` in `Kotlin`:

```
interface OnItemClickListener {
    fun onItemClick(view: View)
}

public lateinit var onItemClickListener: OnItemClickListener

public fun setItemClickListener(itemClickListener: OnItemClickListener) {
    this.onItemClickListener = itemClickListener
}
```

I want to use it in my `Fragment` with `Lambda` like this:

```
    adapter.setItemClickListener {
        // do stuff here
    }
```

But this error appears:

> Error:(54, 39) Type mismatch: inferred type is () -> Unit but SSUpdatesAdapter.OnItemClickListener was expected

I know that I can just implement `Adapter.AddOnItemTouchListener` but I really want to know more about `Kotlin` and how to use `Lambdas`

Answer (score 2):

The feature you are trying to use (single function interface to lambda) only works when the interface was written in Java code.

The reasoning behind this is this:

> "since Kotlin has proper function types, automatic conversion of functions into implementations of Kotlin interfaces is unnecessary and therefore unsupported"

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#sam-conversions